# Python multiprocessing manager dict bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I was working on a bigger example on sharing data while multiprocessing when I stumbled upon this weird behavior with a multiprocessing Manager dict.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
mgr = Manager()
d = mgr.dict()
if not d:
    print("not d is True")

if not d == None:
    print("d == None is false")
```

Output:

```
not d is True  
d == None is false
```

Am I doing something wrong ? If yes could someone please tell me what it is. If not, is this a bug ?

Seen in Python 2.7 and Python 3

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not an inconsistency, `not d` and `d == None` test two different things.

---

`not d` returns `True` for any `d` that evaluates to `False` in a boolean context. E.g., for all the following x, `not x` is `True`:

- `x = 0`
- `x = []`
- `x = ()`
- `x = ""`
- `x = {}`
- `x = None`

You can ask Python whether it evaluates an object as True/False by casting to a boolean explicitly:

```
>>> bool(d)
False
```

---

`d == None` tests whether `d` is exactly the `None` singleton (for this reason, it's idiomatic to write `d is None` instead of `d == None`). Using some of the same examples as above:

```
>>> {} == None
False
>>> [] == None
False
>>> False == None
False
>>> None == None
True
```

---

Boiling it all down, your two tests reduce like so:

`if not d`

- `if not bool(d)`
- `if not False`
- `if True`

`if not d == None`

- `if not (d == None)`
- `if not False`
- `if True`

which matches your output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has added to my understanding of `None`